# Why git lfs get stuck when uploading lfs files

Tags: git, git-lfs

[image: The Git gui stuck at here]

When I installed git-lfs in the repository, every time I upload the file, it first upload the large file and stopped, Now I can't upload the other files.

Comment: Maybe this [github issue](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/347) can help you.

Comment: Try running your command from the command line with `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRANSFER_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1`.  That should give you a hint where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you all,finally I uninstall the git-lfs and pull the whole master branch again